# How do I create a function in Haskell that parses lists of strings from its concrete syntax into its abstract syntax?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

My Assignment:

> A plain text database consists of a number of lines (each line is
> called a row), with on each line a fixed number of fieds separated by
> a single space. The first row a database table is called the header
> and contains the names of the columns in the table. An example of such
> a database would be:
>
> ```
> first last gender salary
> Alice Allen female 82000
> Bob Baker male 70000
> Carol Clarke female 50000
> Dan Davies male 45000
> Eve Evans female 275000
> ```
>
> One way of modeling such databases in Haskell would be using the
> following types:
>
> ```
> type Field = String
> type Row = [Field]
> type Table = [Row]
> ```
>
> A field is always modeled as a string (even though the database may
> contain strings that look very much like numbers), a row is a list of
> fields and a table a list of rows. The head of this list corresponds
> to the header of the table. (A valid table always has a header and
> always has at least one column.) There are several “problems” with
> this model: for example, it does not enforce that each of the rows in
> the table must have the same number of fields. However, for the
> purposes of this first assignment it will suffice. You may assume that
> all the databases that are presented to program will be well-formed,
> that is to say, they will always have the same number of fields on
> each line. The form in which data is stored inside a file, printed or
> written on paper, or entered from the keyboard is called its concrete
> syntax. The form in which data is manipulated inside a program is
> called its abstract syntax. The process of transforming some object
> represented in its concrete syntax into its representation in abstract
> syntax is called parsing.
>
> **Exercise 1.** Write a function `parseTable :: [String] → Table` that
> parses a table represented in its concrete syntax as a list of strings
> (each corresponding to a single line in the input) into its abstract
> syntax. (Hint: use the function words from the Prelude.)

My solution:

They're asking to convert a list of lines (rows) to be converted from conrete to abstract syntax and advised using the words function. I thought that the answer should be `parseTable Row = words Row`, because I take an argument Row from the model and using words Row I turn it into something that you can manipulate. This, however, isn't correct and I'm wondering why and if you guys can help me out.

Comment: Something that starts with an uppercase, like `Row` is not a variable, it is a data constructor, or a type constructor (or a typeclass, etc.).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, if I use row instead of Row it's also wrong, am I thinking in the wrong way? Should it even be parseTable (some argument) = words (some argument)?

Comment: You can only apply `words` to a string, not a list of strings. But Haskell has a handy function that applies a function to each element of a list...

Comment: @RobinZigmond would parseTable row = map words row be the desired solution, because map will apply words to every row given?

Answer (score 0):

First, `Row` is a type, not a variable. You would want to write `row` instead to represent an actual variable of type `Row`.

Now onto your problem. Your table is organized in rows and columns. Each row is separated by newline characters, which means that you can use the function `lines` to get a list of each row string. Then, on each row string, you can use `words` to get a list of each word. So:

```hs
type Field = String
type Row = [Field]
type Table = [Row]

parseTable :: String -> Table
parseTable t = words <$> lines t
```

Edit: Also, while we're on it, I don't know why you wanted to pass a `Row` as an argument to your function which is supposed to *parse* your table. Doesn't that imply that you're taking a raw string as an argument? In any case, this is what I did.

---

**Edit:** I did it in `ghci` and it works fine.

```hs
*Main> :t rawtable
rawtable :: [Char]
*Main> putStrLn rawtable
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff
000 111 222
ggg 333 h44
*Main> parseTable t = words <$> lines t
*Main> parseTable rawtable
[["aaa","bbb","ccc"],["ddd","eee","fff"],["000","111","222"],["ggg","333","h44"]]
*Main>
```

As I said, the goal of your function is to take **the raw string** and parse it into a table, and not to take the list of rows.

However, if you still want to use the list of rows, consider one of the four following lines:

```hs
parseTable t = words <$> t
parseTable t = map words t
parseTable = (<$>) words
parseTable = map words
```

Those are the exact same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got an error though trying to run this answer: Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [String]
    * In the first argument of `lines', namely `t'
      In the second argument of `(<$>)', namely `lines t'
      In the expression: words <$> lines t

Comment: You probably used a list of strings representing rows instead of the raw string representing the whole table I talked about. Editing my answer.